# Oracle SQL Select Every Nth Row (Without Using MOD)

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey all so I am trying to select every Nth row from a table.

I know how to do this using the MOD function with a sub query. However I am only interested in finding solutions that do not use the built in function, MOD.

Any ideas or any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use the `mod` function.

Comment: Simply to exercise my knowledge. I would like to become more independent from using built in functions or libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You can emulate the `mod()` function (which is the right way to do this).  For instance, to get every 10th row:

```
select t.*
from (select rownum as rn, t.*
      from table t
     ) t
where rn - trunc(rn/10)*10 = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for this relatively simple emulation of MOD. I will be sure to tinker around with this.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point can be analytic function [NTH_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions125.htm#SQLRF30031).
However by default, it will return only the first 9th row, not each 9th row.
Maybe you can achieve it with some sub-queries.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting note.

Answer (score 1):

Divide ROWNUM by N - if it's an integer accept it:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT t.*, ROWNUM AS RN
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t)
  WHERE RN / 10 = TRUNC(RN / 10)
```

Share and enjoy.